# How to get Oracle Rows as Columns with count .?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Here is my table view. [column names & records].

```
MERCHANT_ID |CARD_TYPE  |DENOMINATION   |STOCK_IN_HAND

1000017     |CDMA_PP    |1000           | 5 
10000000    |CDMA_PP    |50             | 1 
10000000    |CDMA_PP    |500            | 1 
10000000    |CDMA_PP    |1000           | 1 
10000001    |CDMA_PP    |1000           | 1
```

Now my requirement is need to create table with seperate columns for those card_denominations.

```
MERCHANT_ID |CARD_TYPE  |500       |1000     |STOCK_IN_HAND

1000017     |CDMA_PP    | 0        | 1       | 1
10000000    |CDMA_PP    | 1        | 1       | 2
10000001    |CDMA_PP    | 0        | 1       | 1
```

so please help me to sort out this issue.
[stock in hand shows total cards ]
thanks.

Comment: Since you tagged this with PIVOT, you know the proper term...have you tried writing the query?  It would be really helpful to see your attempts at getting the final result.

Comment: i tried with mentioned links.but those are not yet supported 
.version 11 upwards must.?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a starting point:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(
SELECT 1000017  as merchant_id   ,'CDMA_PP' as cardtype, 1000 as denomination, 5 as stock from dual 
UNION ALL SELECT 10000000,'CDMA_PP',50,1 from dual 
UNION ALL SELECT 10000000,'CDMA_PP',500,1 from dual 
UNION ALL SELECT 10000000,'CDMA_PP',1000,1  from dual
UNION ALL SELECT 10000001,'CDMA_PP',1000,1  from dual
)
PIVOT
(SUM(stock)
FOR denomination in (50,500,1000))
```

Comment: thanks dear Dibstar.but when i added final part PIVOT (SUM(stock)FOR denomination in (50,500,1000) part  then its shows error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended